# How to create a self signed certificate use Python and Flask

Tags: python, flask, certificate, pyopenssl, pkix

My Applications are running as Docker containers.

1. User interface using angular js
2. Middleware ( running in a python flask server on some port)
3. Database

Now I want to create SSL certificate in UI and Python flask server using OpenSSL. I have used same certificate in both Docker container those are expose with out side world with Nodeport.

i.e, UI is running on https://10.0.0.1:31112, this is connecting to https://10.0.0.1:31113.

But From the browser if I want to access the whole application by accepting one certificate. But the application is accessable if i accept those two certificates (i.e, two URL acceptance one after other), which the customer doesn't want to.

Comment: See [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) You will also need to place the self-signed certificate in the appropriate trust store.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible to access non secure url without conforming certificate by end user.

Either end user has to accept that this is non secure url with self sign certificate or you need buy the certificate for you domain from domain registrator